# Write to the system's standard error in Progress

Tags: stderr, progress-4gl, openedge

I am writing a small program in Progress that needs to write an error message to the system's [standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)). What ways, simple if at all possible, can I use to print to standard error?

I am using [OpenEdge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenEdge) 11.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When on Windows (10.2B+) you can use .NET:

```
System.Console:Error:WriteLine ("This is an error message") .
```

together with

```
prowin32 2> stderr.out
```

Comment: Yes, this is perfect! I wish there was a way to perform this type of action with the "native" Progress language, but this did the trick thank you!

Comment: What is the significance of the full stop?

Comment: The full stop terminates a statement in ABL.

Answer (score 1):

Progress doesn't provide a way to write to stderr - the easiest way I can think of is to output-through an external program that takes stdin and echoes it to stderr.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into LOG-MANAGER:WRITE-MESSAGE. It won't log to standard output or standard error, but to a client-specific log. This log should be monitored in any case (specifically if the client is an application server).

From the documentation:

> For an interactive or batch client, the WRITE-MESSAGE( ) method writes the log entries to the log file specified by the LOGFILE-NAME attribute or the Client Logging (-clientlog) startup parameter. For WebSpeed agents and AppServer servers, the WRITE-MESSAGE() method writes the log entries to the server log file. For DataServers, the WRITE-MESSAGE() method writes the log entries to the log file specified by the DataServer Logging (-dslog) startup parameter.

```
LOG-MANAGER:WRITE-MESSAGE("Got here, x=" + STRING(x), "DEBUG1").
```

Will write this in the log:

```
[04/12/05@13:19:19.742-0500] P-003616 T-001984 1 4GL DEBUG1    Got here, x=5
```

There are quite a lot of options regarding the LOG-MANAGER system, what messages to display, where the file is placed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way, but in Unixen you can always do something like this using [OUTPUT THROUGH](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/pdsoe/PLUGINS_ROOT/com.openedge.pdt.langref.help/rfi1424920252896.html) (untested):

```
output through "cat >&2" no-echo unbuffered.
```

Alternatively -- and this *is* tested -- if you just want error messages from a batch-mode program to go to standard out then

```
output through "tee" ...
```

...definitely works.